# How can I use an array to create subdirectories using mkdir in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, mkdir

I am trying to create a number of directories and subdirectories in one single command (ie avoiding for loops) like so:

```
mkdir -p {20..30}/{1..5}
```

This works no problem, and creates 10 directories, and inside each of them, it creates another 5. All good.

However I'd like to replace the subdirectories with an array, but this doesn't work as I expect.

For example, if I create:

```
tru=(1 2 3 4 5)
```

and do:

```
mkdir -p {20..30}/${tru[@]}
```

this is interpreted as

```
mkdir -p {20..30}/1 2 3 4 5
```

and only one subdirectory is created with name "1".

How can I make mkdir interpret my new array in a similar way to how it's doing with {1..5}?

Comment: Brace expansion is different to array expansion. Use a loop.

Comment: Thanks! But I wanted to do this in just one single command, rather than using a for loop. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: In theory, you can simulate a "dynamic brace expansion" using an `eval`, i.e. `tru="{1..5}", eval "mkdir -p {20..30}/$tru"`, but this is ugly; I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're accepting hacky answers:

- use `printf` to generate a comma-delimited list of array values
- wrap in braces `{}`
- feed the `mkdir/printf` to `eval`

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ echo mkdir -p sub{1..3}/{$(printf "%s," "${tru[@]}")}
mkdir -p sub1/{1,2,3,4,5,} sub2/{1,2,3,4,5,} sub3/{1,2,3,4,5,}

$ eval mkdir -p sub{1..3}/{$(printf "%s," "${tru[@]}")}

$ find . -type d | sort -V
.
./sub1
./sub1/1
./sub1/2
./sub1/3
./sub1/4
./sub1/5
./sub2
./sub2/1
./sub2/2
./sub2/3
./sub2/4
./sub2/5
./sub3
./sub3/1
./sub3/2
./sub3/3
./sub3/4
./sub3/5
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It does work for what I need :) 
I thought this would be so much easier though!

Comment: fwiw, if I have to do this a lot I'd use of one dawg's loop-based solutions; it should be (relatively) easy to wrap it in a function so that from an operational point of view it looks like a 'single' command; regards

Answer (score 4):

The working example you have there with `mkdir -p {20..30}/{1..5}` is a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). Implicit in the text produced by the shell expansion is a looping like behavior:

```
$ printf "mkdir -p %s\n" {1..3}/{10..12}
mkdir -p 1/10
mkdir -p 1/11
mkdir -p 1/12
mkdir -p 2/10
mkdir -p 2/11
mkdir -p 2/12
mkdir -p 3/10
mkdir -p 3/11
mkdir -p 3/12
```

The [array expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) from `${array[@]}` is something different:

```
$ arr=(10 11 12 13)
$ printf "mkdir -p %s\n" {1..3}/${arr[@]}
mkdir -p 1/10
mkdir -p 2/10
mkdir -p 3/10
mkdir -p 11
mkdir -p 12
mkdir -p 13
```

So the only way to get what you want (in Bash) is with an explicit loop.

If, for some reason, you need the same **order** in the cartesian product of the brace expansion, you need two loops:

```
for outer in {10..20}; do
    for inner in "${tru[@]}"; do
        mkdir -p "$outer/$inner"
    done
done
```

If you don't mind the order being different, you can do it in a single line:

```
$ for t in "${tru[@]}"; do mkdir -p {10..20}/"$t"; done
```

This loops through the outer first before the inner so the order is a little different. In this case, it does not matter.

Comment: The brace expansion doesn't need the loop: `for t in "${tru[@]}"; do mkdir -p {10..20}/"$t"; done`

Comment: This is so clear! Thanks a lot for this explanation, I didn't know about the term for brace and parenthesis expansion :)

Comment: I have accepted another answer as it does what I needed (ie a one command solution for the problem), but I really appreciate the explanation here.

Comment: @zapatilla: `for t in "${tru[@]}"; do mkdir -p {10..20}/"$t"; done` *is* one line. And using `eval` is potentially risky...

Answer (score 1):

There's a hacky way (but not using the evil `eval`), it require the use of the [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) shell because it permits to have variables inside brace expansion:

```
ksh -c 'mkdir -p {20..30}/{$1..$2}' -- ${tru[0]} ${tru[-1]}
```

or

```
ksh -c '
    tru=( $@ )
    mkdir -p {20..30}/{${tru[0]}..${true[-1]}}
' -- ${tru[@]}
```

```
[...]
mkdir -p 29/5
mkdir -p 30/1
mkdir -p 30/2
mkdir -p 30/3
mkdir -p 30/4
mkdir -p 30/5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it with `eval`:

```
eval mkdir -p '"${tru[@]/#/'{20..30}'/}"'
```

The brace expansion means that the expression evaluated by `eval` is

```
mkdir -p "${tru[@]/#/20/}" ... "${tru[@]/#/30/}"
```

`"${tru[@]/#/20/}"`, for example, expands to the list of (quoted) elements of the `tru` array with each of them preceded by `20/`.

`eval` is best avoided.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Obfuscated, [line noise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_noise), code like the above should also be avoided.

I would use a loop for this.